# CSS hover with nth-child with specific data cells doesn't work

Tags: html, css, html-table

I already saw another question similar to this one, that showed how to add hover to selectors with nth-child. And it does seem to work, but not when I try to target only specific cells (in the later example the class "status" should be a different color and have hover effects).

```css
tr {
  color: white;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: red;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: blue;
}

.status tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.status tr:hover:nth-child(even){
    background-color: white;
}
.status tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: green;
}
.status tr:hover:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td>blue</td>
  <td>big</td>
  <td class="status">available</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>yellow</td>
  <td>medium</td>
  <td class="status">available</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>blue</td>
  <td>small</td>
  <td class="status">available</td>
</tr>
</table>

<p>The "available" cells should be either yellow or white, and when hovered green and orange. Other cells need to be either red or blue.</p>
```

The "available" cells should be either yellow or white, and when hovered green or orange. Other cells need to be either red or blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yXgREG

```
tr:nth-child(odd) .status {
    background-color: yellow;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) .status:hover {
    background-color: green;
}

tr:nth-child(even) .status {
    background-color: white;
}

tr:nth-child(even) .status:hover {
    background-color: orange;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) .status {
    background-color: yellow;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) .status:hover {
    background-color: green;
}

tr:nth-child(even) .status {
    background-color: white;
}

tr:nth-child(even) .status:hover {
    background-color: orange;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: red;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See below. I moved `.status` to the end of the definition.

```css
tr {
  color: white;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: red;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: blue;
}

tr:nth-child(even) .status {
    background-color: yellow;
}
tr:hover:nth-child(even) .status {
    background-color: green;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) .status  {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}
tr:hover:nth-child(odd) .status {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td>blue</td>
  <td>big</td>
  <td class="status">available</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>yellow</td>
  <td>medium</td>
  <td class="status">available</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>blue</td>
  <td>small</td>
  <td class="status">available</td>
</tr>
</table>

<p>The "available" cells should be either yellow or white, and when hovered green and orange. Other cells need to be either red or blue.</p>
```

Comment: The available cell color also changes when you hover over any other cells in that row.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the previous answer, your hover needs to go after the nth-child selector because you need define the element you want to hover first. Also your `.status` class should be at the end of the selector because it is a child of the `tr`.

```css
tr {
  color: white;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: red;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
}

tr:nth-child(even) .status  {
  background-color: yellow;
}
tr:nth-child(even):hover .status {
  background-color: white;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) .status {
  background-color: green;
}
tr:nth-child(odd):hover .status {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td>blue</td>
  <td>big</td>
  <td class="status">available</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>yellow</td>
  <td>medium</td>
  <td class="status">available</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>blue</td>
  <td>small</td>
  <td class="status">available</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you made a mistake. You have to use this

```
tr:nth-child(even) .status {
    background-color: yellow;
}
tr:nth-child(even):hover .status{
    background-color: white;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) .status {
    background-color: green;
}
tr:nth-child(odd):hover .status {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Use this and you will get a solution.

```css
tr {
  color: white;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: red;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: blue;
}

tr:nth-child(even) .status {
    background-color: yellow;
}
tr:nth-child(even):hover .status{
    background-color: white;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) .status {
    background-color: green;
}
tr:nth-child(odd):hover .status {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td>blue</td>
  <td>big</td>
  <td class="status">available</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>yellow</td>
  <td>medium</td>
  <td class="status">available</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>blue</td>
  <td>small</td>
  <td class="status">available</td>
</tr>
</table>

<p>The "available" cells should be either yellow or white, and when hovered green and orange. Other cells need to be either red or blue.</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

you made a mistake. You have to use this

```
tr:nth-child(even) .status {
    background-color: yellow;
}
tr:nth-child(even):hover .status{
    background-color: white;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) .status {
    background-color: green;
}
tr:nth-child(odd):hover .status {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Use this and you will get a solution.